# Unnecessary use of 'and': 'A few seconds later and...'

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

In several books I've read recently I've noticed what seems to me to be the unnecessary use of the word 'and'. For example:

- *A few seconds later and the phone rang.*

Is it even grammatically correct?

Comment: Who's to say what's "necessary"? If you don't like the writer's style, don't read it.

Comment: A very unhelpful answer to a simple question.

Comment: @JohnLawler Who said the poster didn't like it?

Answer (score 4):

I've met this myself in vivid narrative: a temporal phrase usually of the form 'X units later' (X a number) followed by 'and' and a semantically appropriate independent clause. Here are some examples:

> - *Five minutes later and he was in the counselling room with Michael.*
>
> [[Relationship Counselling ... Richard
> Bryant-Jeffries](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Relationship_Counselling_Sons_and_Their/20zpCE35UBIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22minutes+later+and+he%22&pg=PA91&printsec=frontcover)]

.....................

> - *Five minutes later and he was free. He staggered to his feet ....*
>
> [[Back to God ́s Country and Other Stories - Page 146_James Oliver
> Curwood ·
> 2018](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Back_to_God_%CC%81s_Country_and_Other_Storie/zhxwDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22minutes+later+and+he%22&pg=PA146&printsec=frontcover)]

.....................

> - *She sighed and took out her make-up, determined to make the most of her time. Thirty minutes later and she was ready to go.*
>
> [[Love on a Holiday_A.M. Williams ·
> 2018](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Love_on_a_Holiday/Xp5_DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22minutes+later+and+she%22&pg=PT13&printsec=frontcover)]

.....................

> - *Twenty-four hours later and she still felt guilty. Guilty because she'd gone behind his back and guilty because part of her wanted to do
>   it again. At least Gallard had kept his promise and hadn't told
>   anyone.*
>
> [[Exile: A Battle of Souls Novel - Page 185_Elle
> Brice · 2018](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Exile/M8m2DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22hours+later+and+she%22&pg=PA185&printsec=frontcover)]

It's used to invoke drama, partly because of the break in flow the coordinator causes, perhaps partly because it *is* extra-grammatical (rather than ungrammatical ... pushing the boundaries, not overstepping the mark). So I'd say perfectly acceptable (as usual when considering sentence fragments, with the proviso that it's not used too often) in vivid narrative. Significantly, 'X minutes later and' is more common than 'X hours/years ... later and' because of the immediacy of the novels involved.  It wouldn't be appropriate in formal ... say technical ... registers.

And Google ngrams for say 'minutes later and she' show a steep rise in use over the last 30 say years, though many of these examples could be false positives such as 'Joan arrived fifteen minutes later and she ...'.

Comment: +1 for "extra-grammatical rather than ungrammatical". As implied in your very first sentence, this inclusion of an "unnecessary" coordinator seems to be very much a feature of modern "vivid, pacy, immersive" narrative styles. To me, it's also reminiscent of "stream of consciousness" text.

Answer (score 0):

We often skip words when they're implied. In this case, we can skip "It was":

> [It was] a few seconds later and the phone rang.

Grammatical, just informal.